# Why does assigning an ndarray to an ndarray in PyCaffe raise an Attribute Error?

Tags: python, numpy, attributes, caffe, pycaffe

When reading through a Caffe tutorial (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb), I came across the following statement:

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data',
                                  caffe.io.load_image
                                         (caffe_root + 'examples/images/cat.jpg'))
```

It basically serves to assign a single image to `net.blobs['data'].data`.

`net.blobs['data'].data[...]` is a 4D ndarray and`transformer...` returns a 3D ndarray, so the ellipsis serve to copy the 3D array over the 0th axis. This made me think I should be able to rewrite the code to avoid the ellipsis as follows:

```
z3=transformer.preprocess('data', 
                           caffe.io.load_image
                                 (caffe_root + 'examples/images/cat.jpg'))

z4 = z3[np.newaxis,...]
net.blobs['data'].data = z4
```

However, when I do, I get

```
>> net.blobs['data'].data = z4
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Even though,

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = z3
```

works fine. Does this make sense to anyone?

I've verified the shapes and type of my variables as follows:

```
>>> print net.blobs['data'].data.shape, z3.shape, z4.shape
(1, 3, 227, 227) (3, 227, 227) (1, 3, 227, 227)

>>> print type(net.blobs['data'].data),type(z3),type(z4)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> <type 'numpy.ndarray'> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Why does `net.blobs['data'].data = z4` cause problems?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking it works with the `[...]` and not without it, or are you asking why it works with `z3` and not `z4`?  You're not doing the same thing in both of your examples, because one of them has `[...]` at the end of the assignment target and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing `obj.attr = blah` is setting an attribute on the object `obj`, so `obj` controls this.  Doing `obj.attr[...] = blah` is setting an *item* (e.g., the "contents" of some array-like object) on the object referred to by `obj.attr`, so the object `obj.attr` controls this.

In your example, `net.blobs['data']` is some kind of object that won't allow its `data` attribute to be set, so you can't do `net.blobs['data'].data = blah`.  But `net.blobs['data'].data` is an array that *does* allow you to change its contents, so you can do `net.blobs['data'].data[...] = stuff`.  You're operating on two different objects with those two syntaxes (`net.blobs['data']` in one case and `net.blobs['data'].data` in the other).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first method(`net.blobs['data'].data = z4`) is that 'data' is an attribute of net.blobs['data'](which is Caffe **Blob** object) which can not be assigned. If you assign numpy array to the data attribute, you mean "instead of using the memory allocated for data, use the memory of the numpy array", which is **not acceptable**.

But if you use `net.blobs['data'].data[...] = z4`, you mean "copy the data from the numpy array to the memory allocated for the data attribute", which is **acceptable**.

---

For more information, you can read [a similar question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/1TqHBsfj1Zc) in the Caffe Users Group.